# How to async data on InitState method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the color of the shape on the map by choosing a color from a list of colors, as the existing color changes immediately when another color is selected

I used the following code, but the color does not change

I want the color on the map to change directly when I choose another color

```
    
class MapShape {
  MapShape(strPath, this._label, this._color)
      : _path = parseSvgPathData(strPath);


  void transform(Matrix4 matrix) =>
      _transformedPath = _path.transform(matrix.storage);

  final Path _path;
  Path _transformedPath;
  final String _label;
  final Color _color;
}



List colorsData = [
  Colors.teal,
  Colors.pink,
  Colors.purple[700],
  Colors.black,
  Colors.orangeAccent[700],
  Colors.blueGrey[600]
];
int selectedColor = 0;
int index = 0;

Color _color1 = Colors.green;
Color _color2 = Colors.red;
Color _color3 = Colors.amber;
```

```
    
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
.....
            shapes.add(MapShape(
                data,
                printName,
                (_europe_.contains(_world_pays_id_[id]))
                    ? _color1
                    : (_world_numero_pays_.contains(_world_pays_id_[id]))
                        ? _color2
                        : _color3));
          });
        }
      });

      setState(() => {_shapes = shapes,});
    });
  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
.....
       GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context) {
                                      return Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                        child: Card(
                                         
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                            
                                             
                                       
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: GridView.builder(
                                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                  itemCount: colorsData.length,
                                                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                      mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                                                      crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                                                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                                                      childAspectRatio: 2),
                                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                                    return Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          FloatingActionButton(
                                                            onPressed: () {
                                                              setState(() {
                                                                selectedColor = index;
                                                                _color1 =
                                                                    colorsData.elementAt(index);

                                                              });
                                                            },
                                                            backgroundColor: colorsData.elementAt(index),
                                                            elevation: 0.0,
                                                            heroTag: null,
                                                            child: Icon(Icons.done,
                                                                color: index == selectedColor
                                                                    ? Colors.white
                                                                    : colorsData.elementAt(index),
                                                                size: 20),
                                                          ),
                                                          Offstage(
                                                            offstage: index != selectedColor,
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Divider(
                                                height: 1,
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  OutlinedButton(

                                                    child: Text('OK',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                        )),
                                                    onPressed: () {

                                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    });

                              },

                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 8,
                                backgroundColor: _color1,
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: initState must be sync.  Nothing will wait on the future if it returns a future.  And if things must be complete before parts of the page can be rendered with build(), then those portions must be protected by something like a FutureBuilder.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz can you provide me some code please

Comment: Just google for "Flutter initState FutureBuilder".  I'm sure there are plenty of examples.